# properly remove fragments from FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

hey guys i implemented  a `tab layout`(an action bar with tabs)  , basically it is made of using `pagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` below is my code :

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);



    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}






@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
            return tab3;
        case 3:
            TabFragment4 tab4 = new TabFragment4();
            return tab4;
        case 4:
            TabFragment5 tab5 = new TabFragment5();
            return tab5;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}




@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
    trans.remove((Fragment) object);
    trans.commit();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}}
```

my mainActivty:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab4"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab5"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);





    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

now i want to remove the tabs(fragments) and  for that am just removing them from here

```
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab4"));
     if (condition == true){  // do nothing which means don't add the fragment  } 
 else {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab5")); }
```

and is working but not as it supposed to , even after removing the the tab from here `tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab5"));` the fragments are still there and actively performing their task , i want to shut them completely  , am new in android so have no idea about this that its a good approach or not  guys is it enough or not please let me know any guidance will be so helpful for me

Comment: it works ? can you read it one more time ?

Comment: just removing the piece of code i don't think so is proper way for doing it what about those tabs `case 4:
            TabFragment5 tab5 = new TabFragment5();` ??

Comment: Sorry, I read your initial question like you had written something like  "is it working, but I don't think I'm doing it right"

Comment: yeah that was my fault  i have to say that its making the tab  invisible instead of that i said its working , my bad